# Graphical reports are not displayed in Bugzilla; "Image corrupted or truncated"

Tags: bugzilla

When I select **Graphical reports** under **Reports** section in Bugzilla (version 4.0.2), Reports are getting generated but are not displayed, instead it shows cross mark(X) missing image sign & when I debug it with firebug it gives following error "**Image corrupted or truncated**".

I have installed following modules required for graphical report generation:

1. GD
2. Chart
3. Template-GD
4. GDTextUtil
5. GDGraph

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `mod_perl` module. I did that and worked!